# Angular UI Router and Express Router

Tags: angularjs, express, angular-ui-router, passport.js

I'm trying to implement Login feature and there is an redirect after success/failure using Express Router:

```
router.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect:'/dashboard', failureRedirect:'/login',failureFlash: true}),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

and after successfull login, I got `Cannot GET /dashboard` or in case of failure `Cannot GET /login`.
Is there some incompability between routing on the server (Express) and on the client side (Angular UI Router)? Should I use just one of the router and which one?

Here is the the code for UI Router:

```
angular
  .module('app', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngTouch'
  ])
  .config( function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){
    $stateProvider
      .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      })
      .state('home', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      })
      .state('home.dashboard', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html'
      });

    // For any unmatched url, send to /
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $mdGestureProvider.skipClickHijack();
    //remove the hashtag from URL
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your express router is fine. and it was a norm form submit, the page will properly redirect.

But as requests are made through ajax from Angular App, those redirects are not known to the app and hence doesn't do anything.

Make your dashboard or login controller evaluate the login status and then redirect from there.

Comment: There is direct request through the form `<form class="form" method="POST" action="/users/login">
    <div>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input name="username" ng-model="loginForm.username">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input name="password" ng-model="loginForm.password" type="password">
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>` So you suggest that I create logic on the client side controller that will handle redirect using Angular Router (`$state.go('home.dashboard');`) ?

Comment: Yes that should would

Answer (score 1):

The current code you wrote is not redirecting to the front end, its generating a new GET request, you need to handle the GET requests generated.

in your case

```
    router.get('/dashboard',function(req,res){
           res.redirect("full path of the url which you use in browser")
    });
```

or try this

```
{successRedirect:'http://your front end domain/dashboard', failureRedirect:'http://your front end domain/login',failureFlash: true}
```

Comment: I tried with both solutions, still `Cannot GET /dashboard`. Hm, it seems that the problem is on the angular ui router :/

Comment: after hitting login, does the url change in browser?

Comment: ok.. if the url is getting changed in the address box of the browser, press f12 and look for any error in the developer console

Comment: `angular.js:12011 GET http://192.168.1.65:3000/dashboard 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: is your server side having the express.static app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));